# How do I make the video controls show up in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, mediaelement.js

When I hover my video control bar in Chrome, Safari it shows up. But when I hover that in firefox, it's not showing. I don't know if my js code doesn't support firefox. But when I inspect it in firefox, the controls keep appearing and disappearing. Below is my code. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

HTML

```
        <video poster="http://dummyimage.com/320x205/852285/fff" preload="auto">

           <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" />
        </video>
```

JS

```
        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/2.13.1/js/mediaelement.js'></script>

// Video Player
    function videoPlayer() {
        // Exit full screen when video is done playing
        var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
        video.addEventListener("ended", function(e) { 
            video.webkitExitFullScreen()
        });

    var player = $('.video-player'),
    controls = player.find('.vid-play-btn-wrap'),
    wrapper = player.find('video'),
    video = player.find('video').get(0),

    isPlaying = false,
    settings = {},
    media = new MediaElement(video, settings),
    $media = $(media);

    $media.on('play', _playHandler);
    $media.on('pause', _pauseHandler);
    $media.on('ended', _endedHandler);

    player.click(_togglePlayPause);
    player.hover(_mouseOverHandler, _mouseOutHandler);

    function _togglePlayPause() {
        isPlaying ? media.pause() : media.play();
    }

    function _mouseOverHandler() {
        if(!isPlaying) { return; }
        // controls.fadeIn('fast');
    }

    function _mouseOutHandler() {
        if(!isPlaying) { return; }
        // controls.fadeOut('fast');
    }

    function _endedHandler() {
        isPlaying = false;
        video.load();
        controls.show();
    }

    function _playHandler() {
        isPlaying = true;
        controls.hide();
    }

    function _pauseHandler() {
        isPlaying = false;
    }

    $('video').hover(function toggleControls() {
        if (this.hasAttribute("controls")) {
            this.removeAttribute("controls")
        } else {
            this.setAttribute("controls", "controls")
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Having the same problem, did you find a solution to this? (The controls do show up eventually, and it's never the same amount of time)

Answer (score 0):

you have this in your script:

`player.hover(_mouseOverHandler, _mouseOutHandler);`

So BOTH functions are executed on hover (which explains the appearing and disappearing). It might be better to create ONE function that contains both things you want in an if/else statement

Comment: but i want to hover to show the controls. For chrome and safari works. But firefox is not working when hover.

Comment: let me know how I can solve that? So if i hover the video, the controls will show in firefox. Thanks.